# Unable to use _ when doing get_partitions Boto3 call for filtering partitions by using Expression param

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, partition, sql-parser

I cannot use `_` when doing `get_partitions` Boto3 call for filtering partitions by using `Expression` parameter:

```py
response = client.get_partitions(
    Expression="partition_name LIKE '%_20231202%-%'",
    ...
)
```

Value of expression: `partition_name LIKE '%_20231202%-%'`  where `_20231202` should match for filtering. But `_` is not getting matched for some reason. Tried various solutions on internet like `\\_` ,`\_`,'[_]', `escape '/'`, `%\u005F`.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I added some sample code to your question -- does that match what you are trying to do? Also, what happens -- does it generate an error, or do you simply receive an empty response?

Comment: Yes , that is correct . Generates empty response .